# Applescript Outlook to get name of email

Tags: outlook, applescript

I am trying to respond back to email and want to include the first name of the person I am responding to based on the known fact that their email is first.last@company.com.

Here is what I have so far but cannot seem to get the email address or name:

```
on run
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set replyToMessage to selection
    if (replyToMessage is "") then
        -- no email selected, don't continue
        display dialog "No email is selected!"
        return
    end if
    set theRecpt to extract name from sender of replyToMessage as text
    set replyMessageSubj to subject of replyToMessage
    set replyMessage to reply to replyToMessage without opening window

    --need variable theName to get name or email to parse here

    if has html of replyMessage then
        log "HTML!"

        set the content of replyMessage to ("<p>Hi " & theName & ",<br><br>This is my email body
    else
        log ("PLAIN TEXT!")
        set the plain text content of replyMessage to "Hi " & theName & "
        This is my email body" & return & (the plain text content of replyMessage)
    end if
    open replyMessage -- may not need to do this, you could just send it
end tell
end run
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: I have tried this:

```
        set sender's address of newMessage to "first.last@company.com"
```

I get the following error:

```
 Microsoft Outlook got an error: Can’t make address of sender of outgoing message id 292223 into type specifier.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set replyToMessage to selection

    if replyToMessage = missing value then
        -- no email selected, don't continue
        display dialog "No email is selected!"
        return
    end if

    set theName to name of (get replyToMessage's sender)
    set replyMessageSubj to replyToMessage's subject
    set replyMessage to reply to replyToMessage without opening window

    if has html of replyMessage then        
        log "HTML!"
        set the content of replyMessage to ("<p>Hi " & theName & ",<br><br>This is my email body ")
    else
        log ("PLAIN TEXT!")
        set the plain text content of replyMessage to "Hi " & theName & "
               This is my email body" & return & (the plain text content of replyMessage)
    end if
    open replyMessage
end tell
```

Comment: I would have never thought to use the apostrophe s on sender as well as the get. Where could I find that documentation? I then used: 
set theName to address of (get replyToMessage's sender)
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"."}
to get the first name. Any idea how to capitalize the first letter of the first name now?